# Concerning placeholder type deduction

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm hereby strictly referring to the c++ draft ([N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)). Given the following example,

```
int&& f();
auto x5a = f(); // decltype(x5a) is int
```

I'm not sure **why the deduced type is `int`, instead of `int&&`**. Scott Meyers said in his book that

> ..., the reference-ness of an initializing expression is ignored.

**However, I couldn't find any paragraph in the above draft which ensures the statement.** Here's the steps I took in order to deduce the type:

1. According to 10.1.7.4.1 [dcl.type.auto.deduct] paragraph 2,

   > A type `T` containing a placeholder type, and a corresponding initializer `e`, are determined as follows:
   >
   > - ...
   > - for a variable declared with a type that contains a placeholder type, `T` is the declared type of the variable and `e` is the initializer...

   **Therefore, `T` is `auto`, and `e` is `f()`.**
2. As per 10.1.7.4.1 [dcl.type.auto.deduct] paragraph 4,

   > If the placeholder is the auto *type-specifier*, ... Obtain `P` from `T` by replacing the occurrences of auto with either a new invented
   >   type template parameter `U` or, ... Deduce a value for `U` **"using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call"**, where
   >   `P` is a function template parameter type and the corresponding argument is `e`...

   **Therefore, `P` is `U`, and `A` is `int&&`.**
3. According to 17.8.2.1 [temp.deduct.call] paragraph 2,

   > If `P` is not a reference type:
   >
   > 1. If `A` is an array type, ...
   > 2. If `A` is a function type, ...
   > 3. If `A` is a cv-qualified type, ...

   **Although `P = U` is indeed not a reference type, `A = int&&` stays that way because the three cases above are not applicable to `A`.**

These are the only paragraphs that I've found which I think is relevant to this particular case. **In conclusion, `U = int&&`, and the entire `T` is also `int&&`.**

I'm definitely missing something here, and I'm not sure what those are. **If you're kind enough to answer this question, would you confine yourself to the formal wording (with the help of the c++ draft or standard)?**

Comment: Don't know bout a quote, but [this](http://thbecker.net/articles/auto_and_decltype/section_01.html) explains everything you will practically need to know

Comment: `f()` is an xvalue of type `int` (though `decltype` automatically adds `&&` to the type of an xvalue).

Comment: @cpplearner According to 8.2.2 [expr.call] paragraph 11, `A function call is ..., an xvalue if the result type is an rvalue reference to object type, ...`. I think the standard says that the type is still a reference.

Comment: @Il-seobBae Yes, but there's [\[expr\]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#5): 'If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.'

Comment: @cpplearner I think you're right. Thank you.